# Are there any killer guide for accessible websites for people with learning difficulties?

Tags: accessibility

I have been tasked with creating a infosite for people with varying degrees of learning difficulty.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any really good guides, tutorials or places to get advice regarding the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to resources mentioned in other answers, here are some that I refer to:

- The W3C's Web Accessibility home page:  http://www.w3.org/WAI/
- Jim Thatcher's tutorial:  http://jimthatcher.com/webcourse1.htm
- Gez Lemon's blog:  http://juicystudio.com/index.php
- University of Illinois HTML best practices: http://html.cita.illinois.edu/

Each of these contains links to other useful resources as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great resource; the one I refer to for sites I create.

http://diveintoaccessibility.org/

Answer (score 1):

The CEUD (here in Ireland) has actually got some [excellent resources for accessibility in ICT](http://www.universaldesign.ie/useandapply/ict). It's well worth a look for any developer.

Answer (score 1):

Good overview here:
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/cognitive-disability-learning-difficulty/

Answer (score 1):

For web applications, my favorite "killer site" is the WebAIM site.  (http://webaim.org/)  I drew on their site heavily while creating the accessibilty guidelines we use at my current organization.

Things I really like about WebAIM: They have created the "WAVE toolbar," an automated tool for checking your website for basic accessibility issues.  They periodically do a screen reader usage survey-- I've found no one else that has comparable data compiled over a number of years.  They have simplified versions of official accessibility checklists.  They are located at a University and are constanty testing and updating their guidelines.